# Putting lambda definition as part of tuple in spark rdd cause huge increase of size

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm maintaining some old spark 1.6 code that still use RDD api.
I had this rdd with String as key and lambda as value, the lambda was:

```
override def setMeasureIdFunction = (a, ctx, _) => {
      if (a.getPodStatus != DispatchStatus.DISPATCHABLE) None else Some { measureId =>
        val realMeasureId = Option(a.getMeasureId).getOrElse(Long.box(measureId))
        a.setMeasureId(realMeasureId)
        (a, MeasureIdSendRecord(a.getPod, realMeasureId, List(a.getMeasSentId), Receivers.MELT, ctx.dispatchType.getFullType, None, a.getLastUpdAuth))
      }
    }
```

Case class in return does nothing other than instance the object.
Anyone knows how this thing can increase memory size of my previous RDD from 880MB to 56GB

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is not clear? What did you change? How do you see the "size"?

Comment: from spark UI, you can see size of input of every stage.
The change that I've done is irrelevant because is not only a change but i had to rework the whole logic to avoid lambda in RDD. Once I've done this, input size remain stable.
I'm searching an explanation for this behavior, on my production scenario the issue is already solved